# jQuery - Doing multiple actions from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been creating a form for my website and it includes some slidedown functions. I have 3 divs and some jQuery to add and remove those divs as necessary.

- When a user clicks a button for the first time, the div expands and a "remove" button appears; the original button get replaced by another button that performs the same thing for another div with different id. This happens 3 times.
- When a user clicks "remove", the div gets removed and the "add another" button gets replaced by the previous "add another" button, and so on.

This works well, until someone decides to remove a div without any order; this induces an "add another" button of the previous div, which, when clicked, does nothing but disappear, as the div is already present.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h2 class="text-center">Vehicle Info</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Year">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Make">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Model">
          </div>
    </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Comprehension/Other than Collision</h4>
    <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Collision</h4>
    <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="load" style="display:none;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h2 class="text-center">Vehicle Info</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Year">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Make">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Model">
                  </div>
            </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Comprehension/Other than Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add another driver?</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p id="show" class="btn call-form">Add another driver</p>
        <p id="show_2" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Add another driver</p> <small>&nbsp;Maximum 4 allowed</small>
        <p id="hide" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Remove</p>
    </div> 

  <div id="load_2" style="display:none;">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h2 class="text-center">Vehicle Info</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Year">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Make">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Model">
                  </div>
            </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Comprehension/Other than Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
    <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add another driver?</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p id="show_3" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Add another driver</p><small>&nbsp;Maximum 4 allowed</small>
        <p id="hide_2" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Remove</p>
    </div> 
    </div>

    <div id="load_3" style="display:none;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h2 class="text-center">Vehicle Info</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Year">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Make">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Model">
                  </div>
            </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Comprehension/Other than Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="col-xs-offset-2">Collision</h4>
            <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deductible:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </div>
    <label for="deductible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add another car?</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p id="show_4" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Add another driver</p><small>&nbsp;Maximum 4 allowed</small>
        <p id="hide_3" style="display:none;" class="btn call-form">Remove</p>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

and the jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).click(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("div#load").fadeOut();
            $("p#hide").hide();
            $("p#show").slideDown();
            $("p#show_2").hide();
        });
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("div#load").slideDown("slow");
            $("p#hide").slideDown();
            $("p#show").hide();
            $("p#show_2").slideDown();
        });
        $("#hide_2").click(function(){
            $("div#load_2").fadeOut();
            $("p#hide_2").hide();
            $("p#show_3").hide();
            $("p#show_2").slideDown();
        });
        $("#show_2").click(function(){
            $("div#load_2").slideDown("slow");
            $("p#hide_2").slideDown();
            $("p#show_2").hide();
            $("p#show_3").slideDown();
        });
        $("#hide_3").click(function(){
            $("div#load_3").fadeOut();
            $("p#show_2").hide();
            $("p#show_3").hide();
            $("p#show_3").slideDown();
        });
        $("#show_3").click(function(){
            $("div#load_3").slideDown("slow");
            $("p#hide_3").slideDown();
            $("p#show_3").hide();
        });
    });
```

I'm new to jQuery and tried creating an if loop, but failed!

So, what I'm looking for is for that "add another" button to perform multiple actions, i.e., add another similar div over and over again 3 times max, with different IDs, so I can use it to get the data accurately in my email via PHP.

If anything is unclear, please let me know, I will make it more clear.

See the output here- http://jsfiddle.net/ms1pak0L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code a little. See if it works for you

```
> var i = 1; $('#show').click(function(){   $('#load_'+i).slideDown();
>   $('#hide').show();  if (i == 3){        $(this).hide(); 
>     }
>     i++; }); $('#hide').click(function(){
>       i--;
>         if(i == 1){
>           $(this).hide();
>         }
>         $('#load_'+i).slideUp();
>         $('#show').show();
>         
>     });
```

Modified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ms1pak0L/1/

Tell me if you need any help

Comment: Thanks, looks good! Just one problem, the remove button is not there for other divs. I have to remove last then it appears for the second last. What I need is a remove button for all divs, so it can be easily removed without disturbing other divs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code,firstly you have not included your script in the `<script></script>` tags. Then in your jquery script,you're trying to select the div with id `"hide","show","hide_2"` etc which don't exist in your script at all.I'm assuming that you do not have a proper knowledge of how DOM elements are linked and used. I suggest going through the documentation on w3School and MDN.

Coming to your question,it is very unclear on what you're trying to ask? Based on what I've understood you're trying to ask how to create a button which would generate div with a certain id when clicked then the code can be as simple as:

```
<button id="clickable",type=button> Click me </button>
```

Then in Jquery you could do:

```
$('#clickable').on('click',function(){
            //function to add the div wherever you want to.
```

});

Now it is not clear from your question whether you want precisely 3 clicks or there can be more. If the user can click more than 3 times,then this skeleton script can work(provided you know how to manipulate DOM).Otherwise you need to create a hidden div element which would increment a counter and then you can take the HTML value of that element to register the number of clicks:

```
<div id="count">count</div>
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('#count').innerHMTL=0;

$('#clickable).on('click',function(){
       var click=0;
      click=$('#count').innerHTML;
      $('#count').innerHTML+=1;
      if(click===3){
          //stop creating divs 
       }

});
```

Beyond this,if you're asking something else,try to rephrase your question better so that solution can be found out.

Comment: <script> tag really? I have added that in my page, see the jsfiddle link. It is just to show plain code. Besides how come you don't see hide, show in the script, it's there mate!

Comment: If you can tell me how to create a div using append that can slidedown. As on researching the stackoverflow, I came to know that append cannot work with the slideDown, as the elements are not visible in the html at first. Other option is to tell me how to make one button to show 3 divs, that are hidden at first.